# Couldn't assign any type to localStorage

Tags: typescript

```
const getAccessToken = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('tokens')) {
      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokens'))['accessToken'];
      return token
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I get an error in localStorage.getItem('tokens') part.

Error:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I tried declaring type :any but still the issue doesn't solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try move the expression `localStorage.getItem('tokens')` to a variable:

```
const getAccessToken = () => {
  let tokens = localStorage.getItem('tokens')
  if (tokens) {
    const token = JSON.parse(tokens)['accessToken'];
    return token
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=4&pln=10&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBBCcQQ0ZiQVAVWAWQSCHDweKo0AAXlAAAoAJTcgB8oAA3ooSu4aOgOdTuW54LAGNBiOgyAw6QE6agAJIKRC8gDkMtRgkN-IlIlSvJN1MF4pKjvR1Ol7M5PIAUsQAPIAOQCBEcgkgNrddoA2oaeszWWHDQBdADclqdTgJZEyYZToAAvhDoMGxdmSmnCV5OFFoMmnTnLbXimy3B4M6BEPABgwQexpfdGJxmOwNZB+LBoOpEp34HoRF4AEQAUVWDEQNX0s6SONn4AcqENwl9kAks6CKm93zIu2D-G111QjgUrmkeFATjbOlGWH0KAQiBhwiu3ySO20QiAYHA4t0LBsFw3BBCUQA)

The issue here is that when you use an expression, compiler cannot associate it with the `if` check that already happened and thus can't give it a correct type, that is `string`. Instead it's still considered `string | null`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the [`!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) operator to assert dominance :p

```
const getAccessToken = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('tokens')) {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokens')!)['accessToken'];
    return token
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Sometimes the compiler needs to be <s>reminded</s> told <s>who is boss ;)</s> what to do